# XSD : ComplexType Element With the Same Name

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to know that a XSD file with two ComplexType named same value is a valid and common XSD file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two global `xsd:complexType` named the same.  You cannot have two global `xsd:complexType` elements named the same either.

You can, however, differentiate either using distinct namespaces.

You can also have non-global `xsd:complexType` elements named the same.  See `Book` in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="BookStore">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Author"/>
              <xsd:element name="Title"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="Shelf">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Author"/>
              <xsd:element name="ISBN"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: good example to explain the answer. To add on to your answer we should write complex-types separately and use reference of those while defining an element. In that the complex types can be reused as and when required .

Comment: @Joshi, if I understand your suggestion, sure, the anonymous `complexTypes` used here to define the two different `Book` elements could have been defined globally and given (distinct) names if we wished them to be available to the definitions of other elements.